# How to use Fortify Scan 16.11 to scan dotnet core with project.Json

Tags: fortify, .net-core

I created a default .Net Core 1.0.1 Class library and changed buildOptions in project.json to include debugType: "Full".  I used the integrated VS 2015 Fortify Scan using 16.11 and I get the errors below.  How should I scan dotnet core to avoid this problem?

Project 'src\providesFileInPackage\providesFileInPackage.xproj' is not configured to output full debug information.  SCA Analysis requires full debug symbols. Would you like to ignore project and continue?
(Project Properties -> Build -> "Advanced" button -> Debug Info -> "Full"
 OR 
 Project Properties -> Compile -> Advanced Options -> Debug Info -> "Full" for VB)

My project json looks like

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "define": [ "DEBUG" ],
    "debugType": "full"
  }
}
```

Comment: Would love to know the resolution for this as I'm facing the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's blaming the `xproj` file and not `project.json` so I tried to add

```
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
```

inside the `PropertyGroup` but to no avail.

In the end I found a workaround by running Fortify from the command line:

```
msbuild MyApplicationSca.proj /p:Configuration=Release /t:Rebuild /m
```

My `MyApplicationSca.proj` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <MySolution>MyApplication.sln</MySolution>
    <Configuration Condition=" $(Configuration) == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <CommonMSBuildProperties>BuildingSolutionFileName=true</CommonMSBuildProperties>
    <RunHPFortify Condition=" '$(RunHPFortify)' == '' ">false</RunHPFortify>
    <HPFortifyPath Condition=" '$(HPFortifyPath)' == '' ">$(ProgramW6432)\HP_Fortify\HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_4.40\</HPFortifyPath>
    <FortifyMSBuildTasks>$(HPFortifyPath)Core\lib\FortifyMSBuildTasks.dll</FortifyMSBuildTasks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Projects Include="$(MySolution)">
      <AdditionalProperties>Platform=Any CPU</AdditionalProperties>
    </Projects>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Clean">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(Projects)" Targets="Clean" Properties="$(CommonMSBuildProperties)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(Projects)" Targets="Build" Properties="$(CommonMSBuildProperties)"
             StopOnFirstFailure="true" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Rebuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(Projects)" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="$(CommonMSBuildProperties)"
             StopOnFirstFailure="true" />
  </Target>

  <UsingTask TaskName="Fortify.CleanTask" AssemblyFile="$(FortifyMSBuildTasks)" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="Fortify.TranslateTask" AssemblyFile="$(FortifyMSBuildTasks)" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="Fortify.ScanTask" AssemblyFile="$(FortifyMSBuildTasks)" />

  <Target Name="FortifyBuild" AfterTargets="Build;Rebuild" Condition="$(RunHPFortify)">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <BuildID>MyApplication</BuildID>
      <HPFortifyLogsDir>..\HPFortifyLogs\</HPFortifyLogsDir>
      <PackagesDir>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\packages\</PackagesDir>
      <OutDir>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\MyApplication\bin\$(Configuration)\net452\win7-x64\</OutDir>
      <SCATargetBinary>$(OutDir)MyApplication.exe</SCATargetBinary>
      <FPRFilePath>$(HPFortifyLogsDir)MyApplication.fpr</FPRFilePath>
      <SSCUploadToken Condition=" '$(SSCUploadToken)' == '' ">1cfe9977-905c-4da4-bb57-97e3dcc33099</SSCUploadToken>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <TranslateTaskReferences Include="$(OutDir)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <CleanTask BuildID="$(BuildID)" />

    <TranslateTask
      BuildID="$(BuildID)"
      VSVersion="14.0"
      JVMSettings="-Xmx1000M"
      BinariesFolder="$(SCATargetBinary)"
      References="@(TranslateTaskReferences)"
      LogFile="$(HPFortifyLogsDir)sca_translate_task.log">
    </TranslateTask>

    <ScanTask
      BuildID="$(BuildID)"
      JVMSettings="-Xmx1000M"
      LogFile="$(HPFortifyLogsDir)scan_task.log"
      Output="$(FPRFilePath)" />

  </Target>

</Project>
```

I am not investigating more than that right now but I hope this brings us a bit closer to the answer.

Comment: Hello @KevinG, what is %BUILD_CONFIG% and how can I get MSBuild.GlobalRelay.targets? Can you help with sample project where this solution worked?

Comment: @yayadavid I realized there are useless things in my example file. I've edited my answer to address your questions but I can't create a sample project right now - I'm making a note to improve my answer later