# Running Fortify scan on .Net Core libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, fortify

We are having an issue running Fortify scan on .Net core libraries. Pretty much the Fortify scan is not picking up the .Net core libraries however it is working fine for .Net 4.5 libraries.

```
sourceanalyzer -verbose -debug -logfile F:\..\whatever.log -Xmx1200M -Xms600M -Xss24M -b "AppName" -dotnet-version 4.0 -libdirs lib\ : *.dll;
```

We tried the PS command without the  " -dotnet-version 4.0” option and still see the same issue.  Any assistance or feedback would be much appreciated. We are using .Net core 1.0 version.

Comment: Seeming as .NET Core / DNX **is not** the same thing as .NET Framework 4.0 why are you surprised?

Comment: Not suprised..how do I run the scan? thanks

Comment: Fortify doesn't support .NET Core yet

Comment: @Faizal take a look at the link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731716/how-to-use-fortify-scan-16-11-to-scan-dotnet-core-with-project-json

Comment: @Faizal .NET Core is supported in Fortify SCA 17.20

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same issue for SonarQube and dotnet core
may be it helps
here is the cause and how to resolve

By default dotNet Core projects doesn't add the project GUID in the project file.

If you compile the .csproj file you need to put the ProjectGuid manually in the project file it matters for SonarQube analysis task

for each .csproj file,  you can generate a new GUID by using visual studio menu (Tools → Create GUID)

[image]

but if you compile a .sln file which contains a dotNet Core project then the ProjectGuid property doesn't matter  for SonarQube analysis task

see https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild